# how to call in built android Music menu in my development?

Tags: android, get

I would like call android Music which has in built in android device/emulator.I have created a button when i click on button i would like to get Music functionality into my application

I have written button event as follows:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.getMusic)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Here i would like to get android music
        }
    });
```

please any body help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the default music player. You can use an `Intent`

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.getMusic)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
            File file = new File(<URI of your media>);  
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i would like to call Music option which is available in android device.Or i would like to call default music library path into app.how can i do?

Comment: I am still not sure if I understood this properly. If you want to browse for music, select one and play it using the default player, the other answer is what you need.

Comment: how can i get path of audio files?

Answer (score 2):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        //  //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String path = "";
                path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                Intent intent1= new Intent(path);
                intent1.setType("audio/mp3");
                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "select music"), 1);
                onResume();
            }
        });
          public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            switch(requestCode)   
            {
            case 1:  
 Uri selectedAudioUri = data.getData();

                String selectedAudioPath = getPathAudio(selectedAudioUri);


                break;

}
}
}
private String getPathAudio(Uri uriAudio) {    
        //String selectedImagePath;
        //1:MEDIA GALLERY --- query from MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
String selectedAudioPath="" ;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uriAudio, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null){
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            selectedAudioPath = cursor.getString(column_index);

        }else{
            selectedAudioPath = null;   
        }

        if(selectedAudioPath == null){
            //2:OI FILE Manager --- call method: uri.getPath()
            selectedAudioPath = uriAudio.getPath();
        }


            }


        return selectedAudioPath;
    }
```